# Log4net not inserting data into table - neither shows any error

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, log4net, log4net-configuration

I tried using log4net for logging info into db and I stuck with it now.Not sure what I am doing wrong.Whatever  message i send its not received in the database,neither shows any error

I have a C# basic  WINForm application and I am trying to insert log into db.

My log4net.xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="ADONetAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="ADONetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ADONetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="Data Source=CTI-OPT780-06\MSSQL2008; Initial Catalog=MYDB; Integrated Security = True;" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO [Log] ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date"/>
      <dbType value="DateTime"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="255"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="50"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="255"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="4000"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message"/>
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception"/>
      <dbType value="String"/>
      <size value="2000"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout"/>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@context" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="512" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%x" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

C# code to access it :

```
private ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DBAccess));

public TestDB()
{
    logger.Debug("Here is a debug log.");
    logger.Info("... and an Info log.");
    logger.Warn("... and a warning.");
    logger.Error("... and an error.");
    logger.Fatal("... and a fatal error.");
}
```

Create table for Log

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log]
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Thread] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
    [Context] [varchar](512) NULL,
    [Level] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [Logger] [varchar](512) NOT NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [Exception] [varchar](2000) NULL
)
```

It would really great if someone points me where I m making mistake . Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to specify the table in the configuration file, i.e. (sorry, had to replace @ with 'at' in order to post this as a  comment):
<commandText value="INSERT INTO **dbo.PROGRAMLOGS** (Time_Stamp,ApplicationId,UserId,HostId,Thread,Log_Level,Logger,Msg,Exception) VALUES ('at'log_date, 'at'applicationid, 'at'userid, 'at'hostid, 'at'thread, 'at'log_level, 'at'logger, 'at'msg, 'at'exception)" />

Comment: @Martin is it needed ? I haven't put any entry in configuration file ...

Comment: I should mention that I don't have any first-hand experience with log4net. But how would log4net know where to save the log entries unless you provide a table name, either in the configuration file or in code?

Comment: Should have looked at your example closer - I missed that you are actually providing the table name, sorry. Have you checked the first example on this page: [Apache log4net config examples](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)?

Comment: yeah I did. its almost same as what I have . I like to know is there any way to debug this and know whats going wrong

Comment: First rule of thumb with log4net issues is to enable internal log4net debugging.

Comment: In addition to whatever debugging log4net includes, you may want to use SQL Profiler to see what SQL commands are actually being sent to the server

Comment: Hi All, thanks for your wonderful help .Its so stupid of me I didnt  "configure" . Added log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(sFIleName + "\\log4net.xml")); and everything got fixed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your wonderful help .Its so stupid of me I didnt do  "configure" .

Added

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(sFIleName + "\\log4net.xml"));
```

and everything got fixed..

Using the debug trace as told by @sgmoore also helped to fix the db access rights issue.